# Implementing UInt15 in Swift or any other custom integer or float custom type

Tags: swift, type-alias

Is there a simple way to implement a numeric type (integer or float) that is constrained in what value you can assign to it. My ultimate goal is to have a `UInt15` type that is an integer between `0` and `32767` and other similar types.

E.g. I could do the following:

```swift
    typealias HumanAge = Int
```

In this way, I make sure that age is always an integer.

If I do:

```swift
    typealias HumanAge = UInt8
```

Not bad, now it is constrained to an unsigned integer between `0` and `255`.

But humans do not live that long, so how would I implement a `HumanAge` type that is an unsigned  `Int` and is constrained between say `0` and `100` or e.g. a `TeenAge` type that is an unsigned  `Int` constrained between `13` and `19`?

Comment: just use `Int` and restrict the input range

Comment: The easiest way to restrict the age input is to use a `UIPickerView` or a using a `UIDatePicker` to input DOB (preferred considering that the age is not static) with a minimum/maximum date subtracting `n` years

Comment: Clear. So, my approach to create constrained types would be overcomplicating things? I can explain my original reasoning. I will have a number of fields whose input will have to be constrained. But the using/reusing some UI picker with constraints defined does clarify things for me, thank you!

Though, theoretically, it is still interesting whether there is an easy way to constrain a type in Swift.

Comment: I like using ranges for things like that. In simple use case, you can just define it as a constant, and check against it. Or you can define a protocol for a ranged type, and implement it for Int8 or whatever the type you want. Something like this: https://oleb.net/blog/2015/09/swift-ranges-and-intervals/

Comment: In particular for this, see the note on UInt in the language guide. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html "Use UInt only when you specifically need an unsigned integer type with the same size as the platform’s native word size. If this isn’t the case, Int is preferred, even when the values to be stored are known to be nonnegative." This is a similar problem, and you should almost certainly implement it as Int. Control of the range should be handled by the containing type (i.e. "Human").

Comment: The main trouble with range-restrictions is that the type then is incompatible with every related type. Do you really want to make different kinds of ages non-comparable, i.e. `teenager.age < adult.age` would be an error? Or do you plan to write a ton of `<` operators to handle all the different type combinations? And should `teenager.age += 1` crash when the person turns 20? Worse yet, should `age + 10 - 10` crash? (Try evaluating `UInt(1) - 2 + 2`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Rob Napier, re. implementing it as an `Int` and not `UInt`. I remember reading about it and it does make things simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be an overkill for your problem, but I guess property wrappers should be able to help you out here

```
@propertyWrapper struct AgeRestrictedInt {
    var range = 0 ... 100
    var wrappedValue: Int? = nil {
        didSet { if let unwrappedValue = wrappedValue {
            if range ~= unwrappedValue {
                return
            }
            else {
                wrappedValue = nil
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

You can now declare your ages as

```
@AgeRestrictedInt var normalHumanAge: Int?
@AgeRestrictedInt(range: 13 ... 19) var teenAge: Int?
```

And now if you assign value to these variables

```
        self.normalHumanAge = 1
        debugPrint(self.normalHumanAge) // optional (1)
        self.normalHumanAge = 500
        debugPrint(self.normalHumanAge) // nil
```

Similarly

```
        self.teenAge = 14
        debugPrint(self.teenAge) //optional (14)
        self.teenAge = 30
        debugPrint(self.teenAge) // nil
```

You can specify custom range values for each of your variables as well as you can decide what will be the default value if the value assigned exceeds range specified (for example here am setting it to `nil`)

Comment: Thank you, Sandeep. I guess this is the answer I was looking for. I vaguely remembered that I saw something similar. Now I have looked up the property wrappers section in the Swift docs and they explain the property wrappers using the idea of constraining a number to be 12 or less :) Your answer is straight to the point!

Comment: I understand there are still considerations whether to implement this method in a project or not but in general property wrappers are a great feature.

Comment: @hkdalex: Am glad I could help :) Hope am not being greedy, if you decide to implement it please consider accepting it as answer :)

Comment: @hkdalex: Thank you :)

Comment: I was sure I did it. Done now, thank you again!